# Docker image creation failing in centos

Tags: docker, java-11

Please see the snippet of my docker file

```
    FROM openjdk:11-jdk-slim
    #Add packages
    RUN apk add openssl
    RUN apk add curl
    -----
```

While running the build I am getting the below error

```
 [INFO]  ---> Running in a915a8437b69
[INFO] /bin/sh: 1: apk: not found
[INFO] 
[ERROR] The command '/bin/sh -c apk add openssl' returned a non-zero code: 127
[WARNING] An attempt failed, will retry 1 more times
org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Could not build image
```

Please help

Comment: I think the base image you use is using debian. `apk` is the alpine package manager. Use debian's package manager(`apt`) to install new packages.

Comment: I am also facing this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look on the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/blob/178c542fbb93a8f8a42e331b73a1214c9d8ba81d/11/jdk/slim/Dockerfile) of your base image( `FROM openjdk:11-jdk-slim`).

It seems it uses debian thus if you wish to install new software, you have to use distro's package manager, which is [apt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APT_(Debian)).

This becomes clear by checking logs:
`[INFO] /bin/sh: 1: apk: not found`, informing you that `apk` command you are trying to execute does not exist in the container's system.

**Solution:**

You should replace these lines:

```
RUN apk add openssl
RUN apk add curl
```

with

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl openssl
```

and rebuild the image.